# Lenovo Yoga Ubuntu - Track pad not working until after suspend/resume

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad, lenovo-laptop

I have Lenovo Yoga from 2013 running Ubuntu 18.10. When I turn it on I get the the login screen and the track pad doesn't work. If I close the lid and suspend Ubuntu, then open it again, the track pad works again. This happens 100% of the time.

If I use an external mouse, that works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: 18.10 is out of support. Try 19.04.

Comment: Good point. I shall.

Comment: I'm now running 19.04 with the same problem.